# Is it possible to download Halo Spartan Assault and Spartan Strike without having to pay again?

Tags: windows-10, halo-spartan-assault, mobile

I've purchased both Halo: Spartan Assault and Halo: Spartan Strike for my mobile device. I signed into the games on startup using my normal Microsoft account. Today, I just discovered that both of these games are available for the PC, and can be downloaded off the Windows Store. Since I've already paid for them on my mobile device, is it possible to download them off the Windows Store without having to pay for them again?

Comment: do you use the same microsoft account? If yes i suppose it should be possible by going into you accounts apps and loading it from there.

Comment: @Eumel Yes, I did use the same account. How would I get to "account apps"?

Comment: im not using windows 10 so im not entirely sure but i would search for it in the appstore much like with android, i would expect there to be a tab with owned apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably yes, but it depends on what platform you bought it on**

If you bought in on a Windows Platform (Windows 10/10 Phone/8.1/8, Windows Phone 8.1/8) device, yes, it is considered an universal app and can be downloaded on any Windows Platform device but if you didn't buy it from a Windows Platform device, it isn't possible.

As you can see here, it tells me that I can download it on my computer (in Turkish language, sorry): [image: Picture from PC Store]

And I can download it on my phone:
[image: Picture from Phone Store]

Also you can only install it on up to 10 windows platform devices (which should be pretty much enough):

[image: Picture from Phone store, stating that I can install it on 10 devices]

Comment: I checked your stackexchange profile and found no clues about what OS you have on your phone. However I checked the videos of the Android and iOS version of the game and they seem to use Game Center/Google Play Games instead of Microsoft Xbox Live account and while checking your profile I saw that you are studying C# (and you are using a Microsoft mail as your primary mail address), so you might be using a Windows Phone. I guess I went a bit too deep.

Comment: Also the whole Windows Platform Devices can be found [here](http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/04/1.png). (Playing halo on hololens will be cool imho)

Comment: I'm actually currently using an iPhone, but I plan to buy a Windows 10 phone when my lease on it is up.

Comment: @EthanBierlein reminder: If you want you can now award the bounty (the 24 hours grace period passed)

Comment: Still says I need to wait 28 minutes. I plan on awarding it then though. ;)

Comment: @EthanBierlein all I can see about it is "[this bounty is] ending in 6 days", that's why I pinged you.